# How to find the top slow APIs at P99 in the last 7day with Prometheus using PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I want to find the top slow APIs at P99 (99th percentile) in the last 7 days using PromQL.

First, I tried to do:

```
topk(5, quantile_over_time(0.99, api_request_duration_seconds[7d]))
```

But the query execution did not work, I got 500 code error after loading for a while. Then I tried another one:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, sum by (route, method)(
    irate(
        api_request_duration_seconds[5m]  
    ))[7d:])
```

And it did not work too. I guessed because my query consumed a lot of data for the calculator. There is a better way to solve this?